# choosing gui for c++ for cross-platform game

Tags: c++, user-interface, cross-platform

I have just started learning c++ a few days ago and the book I have got does not cover any of the gui aspects in it. Ultimately I am wanting to make simple multilayer games(2-8 players).
I've been doing some reading on gui libraries but have no idea what would be best or what to look for. Is there a gui library you would suggest for cross platform game and why?

Comment: I would suggest getting very familiar with C++ before trying to use any GUI library. If you really want to do games in C++ while still learning it then try to do them on the command line. Also, if you want to do anything with networking or GUIs you also should learn some C in addition to C++.

Comment: I'm very familiar with other languages so thus far c++ isn't that complected. whoever I do not plan on doing anything in the gui until I spend about a month with c++. I'm just trying to gather as much information on guis before I start. Thank you for your comment. As for learning c for networking I will do ^^;; I did not realize I would need to know C for that.

Comment: Is this a 2D or 3D game?

Comment: I'd like on that has both, but if not than I'll stick with 2d for now. Also one that is free preferred. good documentation on the web is a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most applications a typical toolkit like [Nokia's Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) or [WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.com/) is just fine.

If you're planning on having an OpenGL-based game anyhow, you might take a look at [GLUI](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~rademach/glui/) to see if it adds enough tools to make your GUI development easier.

Comment: He means an ingame GUI, not a "GUI" like for "normal" Applications I think :)

Comment: +1: I liked Qt better than wxWidgets but both are good options. Qt also has a OpenGl library as part of the framework.

Comment: so ingame gui has another term possibly? My book and the ones I saw at the bookstore did not address any graphical elements of c++ other then basic text output so perhaps I asked the wrong question. openGL seems like it would be the direction I would like to head in. would I do the graphics in c++ using mathematical equations or would I make my maps, etc in a separate program?

Comment: @yamikoWebs C++ is an excellent language but GUI is a higher level concept that C++ as a language does not care about. That's why there are so many frameworks in many languages to handle GUI. Some are platform dependent like .NET and MFC whereas some like Qt work on Windows, Linux, Mac, mobile, etc.

Comment: @scorcher24: Which is why I included GLUI. The library allows for the rendering of windows entirely in OpenGL. You should be able to use it for windowing in any OpenGL application.

Answer (score 1):

The best free one is CEGUI.

http://www.cegui.org.uk

Why? Because there is no other that can really compete with it.

Ogre3D has some other GUIs too as Plugin, but as standalone CEGUI is leading to my knowledge.

Comment: Never heard of it. Makes for a good afternoon read though thanks for the link ;-)